# How to disable mouse right click in selenium in java

Tags: selenium

I have written an application in selenium using JAVA to login into website. Following is my code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://inernalportal.com");
WebElement element = null;
element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtLoginID"));
element.sendKeys("user");    
element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassID")); 
element.sendKeys("password");
element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
element.click();
```

However above code works correctly but there is one issue, while filling password by Seleinum driver user could click in address bar to see password.

Is there any way to prevent left/right mouse click in Selenium?

Your help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Why would you give this to a user, if you don't want them to see your password? It doesn't seem very secure..

Comment: You could always run the browser as hidden, then the user cant see this at all

Comment: I mean not only in browser; while filling password, user can click at the username filed then in that case selenium will enter password in username field. If we could disable mouse click or keyboard navigation then it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should resolve problem :)

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById(\"txtpassID\").value = \"password\";");
```

Comment: even if you insert it char by char, on submit string present in address bar will have all of them together.

Comment: It doesnt matter how / where you insert it, URL after submission will have it

Comment: I mean not only in browser; while filling password, user can click at the username filed then in that case selenium will enter password in username field. If we could disable mouse click or keyboard navigation then it would solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah, but if you insert password by JS, then click in other place dont have any matter.

Comment: @Son, I tried your suggestion (((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById(\"txtpassID\").value = \"password\";");), it inserts value but then after code wont proceed it stuck at that point

Comment: Strange, I checked that moment ago, and it works good on chrome.
Maybe insert small timeout after execute JS.

Comment: sorry my mistake, its indeed a very good idea son. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Any idea for pressing the button by using JS?

Comment: try ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById(\"btnLogin\").click();

Comment: Thats great. Then please close question.

Comment: @Son, it works very well with ID however when i changed my form from id to name e.g  usename: <input name="txtLoginID"  type="text" > name it wont work with ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementByName('txtLoginID').value = 'xxx';"); any idea??

Comment: it works with  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('txtLoginID').item(0).value = 'xxx';");

Comment: Yeah, getElementsByName return you list of elements, even if you got only one :)

Comment: @Son, you asked me to close this question but truly I don't have any idea how to close answered question :(

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to disable developer tools in browser opened by Selenium driver to hide user id and password?